# Unicode strings in tornado web app

Tags: python, tornado

How can I use unicode strings in tornado views or templates?
I insert in template
`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`
And in view

```
# -- coding: utf-8 --
```

Output is ????

Comment: try: `print u"unicode string".encode("utf-8")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your unicode string ready, the request should end

```
self.render("template.html", aString=aUnicodeString)
```

This renders the file "template.html" setting the aString variable to aUnicodeString.

template.html would look something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        {{aString}}
    </body>
</html>
```

It's also possible to inline the HTML in the Tornado server.

```
self.render('<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head><body>{{aString}}</body></html>', aString=aUnicodeString)
```

More on templates here:

[Tornado Web Server Documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation#templates)