# how to show non ASCII character using python

Tags: python, tornado

[image]

I want to see the original value(in a language other than English) in console(not in a unicode format) without print function. But if I use that code without print function then showing anonymous value(in unicode). I am using tornado framework

Comment: "I want to original value without print function" ?? What does that mean ? What do you want to do original value ? What is that original value ?

Comment: "এই একটি কলম" that is original value

Comment: `print` will print the value of the object. Try something like `my_object = gs.translate('this is a pen','bn')` and then just say `my_object` and enter

Comment: then showing "u'\u098f\u0987 \u098f\u0995\u099f\u09bf \u0995\u09b2\u09ae'".

Comment: can you tell me correct answer alternative of print function?

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of text in your questions (or answers), post the text itself. 1) so it can be indexed by search engines, and 2) so we can copy & paste it.

Comment: Downvoted because the use of screenshot instead of code copy-paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gs.translate('this is a pen','bn')
```

produces a Unicode string. If you just type `gs.translate('this is a pen','bn')` into the interactive interpreter it prints the [representation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) of that string which is

`u'\u098f\u0987 \u098f\u0995\u099f\u09bf \u0995\u09b2\u09ae'`.

But when you type `print(gs.translate('this is a pen','bn'))` the Unicode data is encoded into a stream of bytes using the default encoding (which appears to be *utf-8*) so that the data can be printed.

You can perform that encoding explicitly:

```
uni = u'\u098f\u0987 \u098f\u0995\u099f\u09bf \u0995\u09b2\u09ae'
s = uni.encode('utf-8')
print(s)
```

**output**

```
এই একটি কলম
```

Note that the representation of `s` is the following byte string:

```
'\xe0\xa6\x8f\xe0\xa6\x87 \xe0\xa6\x8f\xe0\xa6\x95\xe0\xa6\x9f\xe0\xa6\xbf \xe0\xa6\x95\xe0\xa6\xb2\xe0\xa6\xae'
```

so that's what would get printed in the interactive interpreter if you typed `s` at the prompt.

You can't get the interpreter to print `এই একটি কলম` simply be typing a variable name or simple expression, since it will *always* show the representation of the variable or expression. So if you want to see the actual Bengali (?) text in the interactive interpreter, you need to use `print` (or `sys.stdout.write`) to tell it to print the UTF-8 encoded data.

Comment: I am using tornado. so here how can I render "এই একটি কলম"?

Comment: @ArifurRahim: I don't use Tornado, but see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5658067/4014959)

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use Python 3:

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> u'\u098f\u0987 \u098f\u0995\u099f\u09bf \u0995\u09b2\u09ae'
'এই একটি কলম'
```